# Horizontal ticker gets cut off prematurely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've implemented a horizontal ticker, however, it should cycle through the `<li>`'s and never stop. It seems I have an error somewhere and at the end of the `<li>`'s **it leaves a black space on the right which shouldn't happen**, it should continue the loop. What have I done wrong here which is making this not work infinitely as it should?

http://jsfiddle.net/UzrM5/

```
/* Horizontal Ticker */
jQuery.fn.racScroll = function(settings) {
        settings = jQuery.extend({
        travelocity: 0.07
        }, settings);       
        return this.each(function(){
                var $strip = jQuery(this);
                $strip.addClass("newsticker")
                var stripWidth = 1;
                $strip.find("li").each(function(i){
                stripWidth += jQuery(this, i).outerWidth(true); // thanks to Michael Haszprunar and Fabien Volpi
                });
                var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
                var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");                             
                var containerWidth = $strip.parent().parent().width();  //a.k.a. 'mask' width   
                $strip.width(stripWidth);           
                var totalTravel = stripWidth+containerWidth;
                var defTiming = totalTravel/settings.travelocity;   // thanks to Scott Waye     
                function scrollnews(spazio, tempo){
                $strip.animate({left: '-='+ spazio}, tempo, "linear", function(){$strip.css("left", containerWidth); scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);});
                }
                scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);             
                $strip.hover(function(){
                jQuery(this).stop();
                },
                function(){
                var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
                var residualSpace = offset.left + stripWidth;
                var residualTime = residualSpace/settings.travelocity;
                scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
                });         
        }); 
};

    jQuery(function ($) {
    $("ul#feed").racScroll({travelocity: 0.05});
    });
```

Comment: @Colandus: For some reason I can't comment on your answer. Strange that it's locked? @Colandus: Nice pickup, thanks! That resolves the cutting off text but the black background should never be displayed. The issue seems that it is moving the entire grey div, whereas I just want the `li`'s to move and the grey background to never disappear..

Comment: I deleted it, because I realized it wasn't what you asked for.

Comment: Ah that's why I couldn't comment. No prob, thanks. It did resolve the text cut off though ;) Now just to work out why there's the big black space..

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the following css:

```
  margin-right: -15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ul#feed li:last-of-type { margin-right:0; }` should fix your problem.

Comment: I think what he means is it's not looping, it leaves a giant blank spot after the UL moves off screen and returns to the starting position. He wants it to be a seamless loop.

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira: Thanks, that's now resolved. The problem is with the grey bar ending..

Comment: @Devin: Exactly right, thank you for explaining so eliquently! :)

Comment: I see... Well, you are moving it as a whole, just pushing it to the left. You might need to end up duplicating the content, unless you make the `<li>` items move instead of the `<ul>`. Sorry, not much jquery experience for that kind of stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution. I suggest adding the following:

```
ul#feed li:last-child {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

What this does is push the last list element by 30px, to overcome the -15px margin in "ul#feed li". Adding just 15px alone, fixes the problem as well, you're left with text from the last list element touching the end of the list.

[Link to the corrected JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/nejj/UzrM5/5/)

Comment: Thanks! As Devin said in comments "I think what he means is it's not looping, it leaves a giant blank spot after the UL moves off screen and returns to the starting position. He wants it to be a seamless loop".

Comment: Thanks Nej, however, it is still leaving the **big black space** after the list items. See updated question outlining this. Thanks!